# Assigning relative force to a projectile fired while orbiting a sphere

Tags: unity, physics, 3d, rigid-body-dynamics, sphere

[Projectile Not Correctly Inheriting Parent Velocity (Unity3D)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/162854/projectile-not-correctly-inheriting-parent-velocity-unity3d?newreg=c55d39c020394605bb02cc113456dd62)

So I am trying to incorporate the above person's changes into a script I am making although

1. I'm no great coder and
2. I'm not even sure their solution works best for what I am doing.

Essentially what I have right now is a high speed shooter where the player is being pushed around as a physics object on a sphere world rather than using translate for movement. I keep finding solutions that would work really well if I was just translating through xyz space. Using a physics object for my projectile has been working well (I can shoot in one direction and have the projectile hit my in the back after circling around) but once I get up to speed I'm in trouble.

I think I've successfully incorporated the projectile portion into my script but currently it keeps shooting on the positive z axis.

On top of that, I'm not even sure where to start incorporating the second half.

Emitter Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpaceShoot : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject Bullet_Emitter;
public GameObject Bullet;
public GameObject target; // Player

public float Bullet_Forward_Force = 100;
public float Bullet_Life = 60;
public float fireInterval = 0.05f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        InvokeRepeating("Fire", float.Epsilon, fireInterval);
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        CancelInvoke("Fire");
}

void Fire()
{
    GameObject Temporary_Bullet_Handler;
    Temporary_Bullet_Handler = Instantiate(Bullet, Bullet_Emitter.transform.position, Bullet_Emitter.transform.rotation) as GameObject;

    Rigidbody Temporary_RigidBody;
    Temporary_RigidBody = Temporary_Bullet_Handler.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    Temporary_Bullet_Handler.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * 90);

    Rigidbody target_rigidbody;
    target_rigidbody = target.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    Temporary_RigidBody.velocity = target_rigidbody.velocity;

    Temporary_RigidBody.AddForce(transform.forward * Bullet_Forward_Force);

    Destroy(Temporary_Bullet_Handler, Bullet_Life);
}
}
```

Edited script as it currently stands. It mostly does what I need although I'm trying to figure out a way to clamp the distance to the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to clamp the projectile's distance from the origin. It's 75% of the way there but that'll do for a Game Jam. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html